# Android studio - "some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database"

Tags: ubuntu, svn, android-studio

In our Android studio environment we get the "some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database" error.

This is an ubuntu machine.

We can commit/update just fine, but this error keeps showing.

Is there anyway to get a more detailed error? I would like to find out if some folders cause this error specifically?

I understand some other users asked similar questions and resolved by installing SVN, but our SVN appears to be working just fine.

Comment: Check out this link it would help to resolve "working copy" issue of svn https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-the-format-of-the-local-working-copy.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by reinstalling Ubuntu in English instead of Turkish.